# Computing ROC curves in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, classification, curve, roc

I'm having difficulties in plotting a set of ROC curves in matlab. I have the following code:

```
if QinitDithered == Qas(iii) 
    % hit
    truePositives(i,iii,ii,1) = 1;
else 
    % miss
    truePositives(i,iii,ii,1) = 0;
end
```

Looking over the [roc()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/roc.html) function in matlab I notice the second parameter(outputs) is a matrix with values in [0,1]. Currently I have the first parameter values. 
How may I determine the second parameter values?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, it sounds like you want to call `roc()` and retrieve all the outputs instead of just the first output, which can be done via `[tpr,fpr,thresholds] = roc(irisTargets,irisOutputs)` from the documentation you linked. Could you include the code where you call `roc`, or add some more detail to your question?

Comment: I cannot call roc() without knowing the values of outputs(the second parameter). Up to this point I have a set of binary values(hits and misses). I can further determine the true positive rate and the false positive rate without calling roc(). TPR = all_ones / number_of_results. The FPR is computed similarly.

Comment: Okay, so this is more of a neural network/characterization question than a matlab question. I can't help you, but hopefully someone can